# move_uploaded_file não funciona

Tags: php

Olá, o move_uploaded_file não esta funcionando e gostaria de saber o por que

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="pegar.php" name="form">
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" value="Escolher">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" height="50" width="10">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**pegar.php**

```
$foto = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
$foto = str_replace(" ", "_", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("á", "a", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("à", "a", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("â", "a", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ã", "a", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("é", "e", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("è", "e", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ê", "e", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("í", "i", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ì", "i", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("î", "i", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ó", "o", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ò", "o", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("õ", "o", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ô", "o", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ç", "c", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("û", "u", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ù", "u", $foto);
$foto = str_replace("ú", "u", $foto);

$foto = strtolower($foto);

if(file_exists("fotos/$foto"))
{
    $a = 1;
    while(file_exists("fotos/[$a]$foto"))
    {
        $a++;    
    }

    $foto = "[".$a."]$foto";    
}

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], "fotos/".$foto))
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
          <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro no upload do arquivo!')</script>";    
}
```

Comment: Deve estar aparecendo um warning na tela com o motivo, não?

Comment: Você precisa especificar o `enctype="multipart/form-data"` na sua tag `<form>`.

Comment: Sim, funcionou certinho, vlw pela ajuda mano.

Comment: por favor, @PauloRodrigues inclua como resposta, o autor da pergunta deve marcar como correto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como descrito no [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp), sempre que for necessário realizar envio de arquivos, o uso do atributo `enctype` se faz necessário, ficando assim:

```
<form method="post" action="pegar.php" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Lembrando que o atributo `enctype` só funciona corretamente caso o atributo `method` seja definido como **post**.